# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient Response Header

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I'm new to ServiceStack so please forgive my ignorance...

How can I the `JsonServiceClient` to give my my `DataContract` response object and also allow me to get the response header with only a single request?

I've figured out how to return a populated DataContract Response object like this:

```
var field1 = "aaa";
var field2 = "bbb";

var client = new JsonServiceClient("https://api.server.com/api");
Response1 response1 = client.Post(new Request1() { Field1= field1, Field2= field2});
```

I've also figured out how to get a response header item from the `HttpWebResponse` overload like this (see below) which requires the slight modification of commenting out the request data contract interface as shown here: 
`class Request1 //: IReturn<Response1>`:

```
var field1 = "aaa";
var field2 = "bbb";

var client = new JsonServiceClient("https://api.server.com/api");
HttpWebResponse response1 = client.Post(new Request1() { Field1= field1, Field2= field2});
var value = response1.Headers.GetValues("Item")[0];
```

But again, how can I do both at once?

I did figure out how to do this with the `.PostJsonToUrl()` extension method but my question is how can I do this with the `JsonServiceClient`.  If anyone is curious here's how I did it with the `.PostJsonToUrl()` extension method:

```
var url = "https://api.server.com/api/method";
string value = null;
Response1 response1 = url.PostJsonToUrl(new Request1() { Field1= field1, Field2= field2},
    null, httpResponse =>
    {
        value = httpResponse.Headers.GetValues("Item")[0];
    }).FromJson<Request1>();
```

Here are my DataContract Classes

```
[Route("/method")]
[DataContract]
class Request1 : IReturn<Response1>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "field1")]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "field2")]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
class Response1
{
    [DataMember(Name = "field1")]
    public long Field1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "field2")]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "field3")]
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [ServiceStack's .NET Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) include both a `ResponseFilter` and static `GlobalResponseFilter` property you can use to inspect the HTTP Response before the response is deserialized, e.g:

```
string myHeader = null;
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl) {
    ResponseFilter = res => myHeader = res.Headers["X-MyHeader"],
};

var response = client.Post(request);
```

Where `response` will contain the deserialized Response body and `myHeader` will be populated with the value of `X-MyHeader` HTTP Header.